# Fast ranking/unranking of combinations (64bit)

Tags: c++, 64-bit, combinations, rank, bitset

There is this great post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3143594/6589735
outlining an algorithm of ranking/unranking combinations.
Also, there are concrete implementations in C++, e.g. here https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/combo/combo.cpp

I am in need of a *very fast* implementation in C++, that does rank/unrank combinations encoded as `unsigned long long` on a x64 Haswell CPU.

My attempt is in great need of improvement.

```
unsigned long long rank(unsigned long long comb, int card)
{
    unsigned long long rank = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= card; i++)
    {
        unsigned long index;
        _BitScanForward64(&index, comb);
        rank += binCoef[index][i];  // the binCoef table is precomputed
        comb &= (comb - 1);
    }

    return rank;
}

unsigned long long unrank(unsigned long long rank, int card)
{
    unsigned long long comb = 0;

    unsigned long long m = rank;
    for (int i = card - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int p = i;
        while (binCoef[p + 1][i + 1] <= m)
            p++;
        m -= binCoef[p][i + 1];
        comb |= (1 << p);
    }

    return comb;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but what is your great question?

Comment: @MSalters: changed language to C++

Comment: Since you're precomputing anyway you could precompute some more, for example the sum of every possible byte of the bitmask. Then instead of looping over the bits, mask them with `pdep`.

Comment: @FirstStep: I have given a C++ implementation of an algorithm. The question is: How can this be improved regarding speed (execution time)?

Comment: Then you are not in the right place. Go to [**CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @harold: I highly appreciate your answer; you already helped me a few days ago with my 1st question here on SO. However, I am afraid I cannot translate your suggestion to working code. Maybe you can help me a bit further (with some lines of code)?

Comment: Maybe not, it turns out to be a bit more complicated than I had anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are already quite well on the way. Are you doing some poker related perhaps? (I just googled unranking algorithms when doing just that). Some considerations:

1) With small amount of items, binomials could be quicker to calculate manually than the memory accesses, but considering long long, this is highly unlikely in your case.

2) However, depending on compiler wits, you might save a memory access with calculating 2D index of the precalc table:

```
binCoef[(index<<6) + i]; // instead of binCoef[index][i]
```

3) Not sure how well the `binCoef` fits in L1 cache during calculations, but you might save half of the lookup space with identity C(n, k) == C(n, n-k) with a cost of one additional conditional. Maybe worth testing?

4) In unrank, I think the internal while-loop is the slowest part. There are two obvious optimizations: Either implement a binary search to locate p, OR...

5) IF you are dealing with small values of `card`, you might even consider full-blown lookup solution to unrank: there are C(52, 5) = 2.6 million poker hands, which is only a few MB of lookup.

6) Similarly, you might see if `map<int, long long> rank` could be used to replace the rank algorithm altogether. A binary tree is O(log N) for lookup, and hashmaps might have even better performance. Just precalc it:

```
map<long long, int> rank5;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) rank5[unrank(i, 5)] = i; //ranks of 5 card hands
```

If you will need large values of `card`, then the lookup methods won't work, and I think you're pretty much stuck with the binary search optimization. Good luck!