# How to calculate specific cards combination index

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

There are 22100 combinations of 3 cards from the 52 cards deck `(52 * 51 * 50 / 3! = 22100)`.

Here is an enumeration of all these combinations:

```
    static const ins cards_count = 52;
    int boardId = 0;

    for (int b1 = 0; b1 < card_count; b1++)
    { 
        for (int b2 = b1 + 1; b2 < card_count; b2++)
        {
            for (int b3 = b2 + 1; b3 < card_count; b3++)
            {
               cout << boardId << endl;
               boardId++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it posssible to write an indexer fucntion that converts b1, b2, b3 to the boardId (without using a map)? If this is hard maybe you can advise some hash fucntion that maps b1, b2, b3 to the int size hash.

Comment: This is a maths problem not a programming problem, and yes I'm sure its possible.

Comment: is it possible? Your code already does that. Well, almost... you just need to add a `if(b1==b1_target && b2==b2_target && b3==b3_target) return boardId`. not the most efficient, but enough to see that it is possible

Comment: @BassemAkl yes, but looks like this formula is not correct;

Comment: @Brans Ds Do you just want to assign and get a unique id for each set of combination (of 3 cards)? If that is the case, there is no need to calculate the number of combinations at all.

Comment: @user3437460 This not so beautiful, but it will ok to for the my task

Comment: Related/dupe for Python: [Compute rank of a combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143142/compute-rank-of-a-combination/3143594) and also related for C++ [Fast ranking/unranking of combinations (64bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590286/fast-ranking-unranking-of-combinations-64bit)

Comment: @Brans Ds Let me know if my solution works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. It's pretty straightforward, too, and I briefly thought about writing down how, but then I realized I need quite a lot of mathematical notation for it.

The idea is to calculate how many combinations come before (or after) the one you need an index for.

The 3 from 52 combinations you state are correct, of course. Now let's enumerate how many come before b1,b2,b3:

- First of all, there are all combinations with the first card smaller than `b1`. You have `b1` options for the first card (since you start at 0), and for each of these options `b1_`, you have `52-b1_` choose `2` combinations. So, this number is the sum over `b1_` from `0` to `b1-1` over said binomial coefficient. With a little of math knowledge, you can derive a closed formula for that without actually evaluting a sum.
- Second, there is all combinations with the first card having index `b1` and the second card having index below `b2`. This is again a sum, but an easier one. You have one choice for the first card (`b1`) and `b2-b1` (might be off by one, check that before you implement it) options for the second card. For each of these options (sum over `b2_`) you have `52-b2` options for the third card. This is a sum over consecutive numbers, and getting a closed formula for that is simple (hint: the sum of the first `n` numbers, starting at `1`, is `n*(n+1)/2`, the sum of consecutive numbers not starting at one is the difference between two sums starting at `1`).
- Finally, you are interested in the number of combinations with the first two cards being `b1` and `b2` and the third being smaller than `b3`. This is simple, since that sum is exactly `b3`.

Only thing you need to do now is add the result from each item, and you have your index. I advise you take a piece of paper, do the math as proposed and get to a simple, easy to evaluate formula you can implement.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply ignore the fact that cards in a set must be unique and sorted. Then your index is simply `card1 + 52 * card2 + 52 * 52 * card3`. With well formed sets not every index is reachable and the distribution is skewed towards lower numbers. Try `hash = index % prime * 52 * 52 * 52 + index` to even out the distribution. Try a low prime. The index part added ensures the hash will remain unique.

Answer (score -1):

If you are only interested to assign and get the unique id of a set of any 3 different cards from a standard deck, there is no need to calculate the number of combinations for various set.

Let the cards in the deck be assigned with 1 to 52.

You could do it  programatically as :

```
int getSetId (int card1, int card2, int card3){
    if (card1 == card2 || card2 == card3 || card1 == card3)
        //throw an exception
    return (card1 * card2 * card3);
}
```

This will give you an unique id for all set combinations.

**Edit 1:**

In case there will be a duplicated id due to the multipliers forming the same product, instead of using 1 to 52, you can use the first 52 prime numbers.

Comment: It returns unique value but it is bad as a hash function. It is producing values only in the beginning, if we divide it output to 6 parts here is distribution:    0.737783
   0.164706
  0.0648416
  0.0246606
 0.00723982
0.000769231

Comment: What are you dividing it by? I thought you just wanted the unique id? No?

Comment: To use it like hash function.. and hash function should produce balanced output to be effective

Comment: I dont understand how this results in unique ids. For example `getSetId(3,2,4)` yields the same id as `getSetId(3,1,8)`, one has to use prime numbers to make it work

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, it will be prime numbers (as already mentioned in my post)

Comment: @Brans Ds If you want to generare hash values, you can apply quadratic probing.

Comment: your answer states: "Let the cards in the deck be assigned with 1 to 52." and then "This will give you an unique id for all set combinations.". The remark about prime numbers looks like a sideremark, but actually "In case there will be a duplicated id" is just the case when you use anything else than primes